# SQL: show value when count is 1

Tags: sql

I have a query to show items having only 1 language versions:

```
  SELECT COUNT(Language), 
         Name
    FROM Fields
GROUP BY Name
  HAVING COUNT(Language) = 1
ORDER BY Name
```

Because in this case Language is unique I would like to have Language as a column in output. Adding Language to GROUP BY doesn't do what I want :(
Other approach would be showing only items from particular language but also with COUNT(Language) = 1.

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another aggregation function (can be `MIN` or `MAX`):

```
  SELECT MIN(Language) Language, 
         Name
    FROM Fields
GROUP BY Name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Language) = 1
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: MIN(Language) worked indeed. I have seen solutions using it but I thought it applies only to numeric fields. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Other options:

```
select f.Language, f.Name
from Fields f
where (select count(1) from Fields f2 where f2.Name = f.Name) = 1
order by f.Name
```

and

```
SELECT  (select Language from fields f2 where f2.Name = f.Name) Language,
         f.Name
FROM Fields f
GROUP BY f.Name
HAVING COUNT(f.Language) = 1
ORDER BY f.Name
```